# responseString from json parse nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I want to parse a json from an url given by soundcloud.

```
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:test[indexPath.row]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];




     NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSData* jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSError *jsonError;
        NSDictionary* allKeys = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];
```

Url has this form:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/195677713/stream?client_id=3e6cb435319c6fdaad56ff5641e0f89e
```

but responseString is nil .

Any ideea why ?

Comment: Have you tried logging the Error value? And if that's 'nil', logging the responseData value?

Comment: data in the url is not JSON  ,must have a valid JSON with a top level container which is an array or dictionary.

Comment: Why did you convert data into string and then back into data? Print your logs with "responseString".